# Restrict fastlane snapshot to iPhone devices

Tags: ios, snapshot, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

We can get automated snapshots in iOS by using [Fastlane Snapshot](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/screenshots/).

There is a config file named `Snapfile` where you can limit the devices list:

```
# A list of devices you want to take the screenshots from
devices([
  "iPhone 8",
  "iPhone 8 Plus",
  "iPhone SE",
  "iPhone X",
  "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)",
  "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)",
  "Apple TV 1080p"
])
```

Now my question is how can I restrict this list not specially to certain devices, just to anything in default configuration where it's an iPhone device as my target is iPhone.

And where is the default list of all devices?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want only iPhones on the device list?

Comment: @rcarba yes only iPhones, but not in listing the iPhone models

Comment: This list takes directly your iPhone's names on XCode. Just change it and write the name of the device you want